# Symbolic identifiers in Scala

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

Classes need not use alphanumerics in Scala.  Which means, the following is allowed

```
class > {

}
```

However, I am having a problem with passing such classes as varargs.  The following code will result in an error.  Anyone know how to get around this?

```
class SomeClass(arg: >*) {

}

class > {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a space between `>` and `*`:

```
class SomeClass(arg: > *) { ... }
```